# Successfully installed pip, but error displayed when viewing pip version

Tags: python, pip, scapy

The command line displays successful installation of pip, but when querying the pip version, it displays Script file 'D:\anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py' is not present.I don't know how to resolve it. Help!!!

I tried many methods, but it seems like I can't use pip. I wanted to call scapy, but I can't use pip anymore.Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Please try reinstall:

```
conda install --force-reinstall pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the PATH variable in your windows? Check that the pip executable is in your PATH variable. To do this, open a command prompt and type echo %PATH%. Look for the directory where pip is installed (likely something like C:\Python3\Scripts).

Now if pip is in your PATH, try running it directly from the command prompt by typing pip and pressing Enter. But If this still gives an error, I think you should try specifying the full path to pip.

Or you should re install it